# react-query persisted data from mutation is inactive and not retrievable

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to persist mutation sign in data for later usage. However, when I check on it the query is set as 'inactive' and useQuery returns undefined data.

Below is my code:

useAuthenticatedUser.js

```
const useAuthenticatedUser = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: PERSISTED_QUERY_KEYS.USER,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // add or remove authentication from axios client
    console.log("useAuthenticatedUser data: ", data);
  }, [data]);

  return {
    authenticatedUserData: data,
  };
};
```

SignIn.jsx (/signIn)

```
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const signInMutation = useMutation({
    mutationKey: MUTATION_KEYS.signIn,
    mutationFn: (data) => client.post("/signIn", data),
    onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
      console.log("Sign in data: ", data);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: PERSISTED_QUERY_KEYS.USER,
      });
      queryClient.setQueryData(PERSISTED_QUERY_KEYS.USER, data);
      navigate("/home", { replace: true });
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log("signInMutation error: ", error);
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    signInMutation.mutate(data);
  };
```

Root.jsx (/)

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { authenticatedUserData } = useAuthenticatedUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(authenticatedUserData ? "/home" : "/signIn", {
      replace: true,
    });
  }, [authenticatedUserData]);
```

main.jsx

```
export const PERSISTED_QUERY_KEYS = {
  USER: ["authenticated/user"],
};

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      cacheTime: Infinity,
    },
  },
});

const storagePersistor = createSyncStoragePersister({
  storage: window.localStorage,
});

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
  {
    path: "/signIn",
    element: <SignIn />,
  },
  {
    path: "/signUp",
    element: <SignUp />,
  },
  {
    path: "/home",
    element: <HomePage />,
  },
]);


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  ...
    <PersistQueryClientProvider
      client={queryClient}
      persistOptions={{
        persister: storagePersistor,
        maxAge: Infinity,
        dehydrateOptions: {
          shouldDehydrateQuery: ({ queryKey }) =>
            findIndex(values(PERSISTED_QUERY_KEYS), (v) =>
              isEqual(v, queryKey)
            ) === -1,
        },
      }}
    >
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </PersistQueryClientProvider>
  ...
)
```

React query devtools screenshot
[react query devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHhtA.png)

What I tried:

1. Load Root (/) -> redirect to SignIn (/signIn)
2. Input data and click on submit (success -> query is saved)
3. Home screen is loaded
4. Load Root again (/)

Expectation:
Query data is loaded -> redirect to Home (/home)

What happened:
Query data is undefined -> redirect to SignIn (/signIn)

Since I am new to react-query, I don't know what cause this issue? Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a query function in `useAuthenticatedUser`. Without the query function `useQuery` probably won't work as expected. https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

Is there a query function for that query? Otherwise you shouldn't use `useQuery` at all, but instead use `useState`, possibly together with a context.

Comment: I see, I thought that `useQuery` can't work without a fetch function. I only need to store the useMutation data in a persisted store (like how redux-persist works for redux). Is there any way to work like that in react-query?

Comment: seems like you get some data back from your mutation that you want to store somewhere and then distribute in your app. You can do that with other state managers; use react-query for things where you have an actual resource to query from the backend.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the two answers